# I have no idea driving EPD display

Tags: stm32, e-ink

I am trying to drive EPD(ED060SD1) using STM32F429ZGT, and got datasheet from display vendor. But there is no specific explanation of how to drive EPD display or details of pin.

So I want to know what those pin does.. and any hint how to run this display..

Thank you

[ED060SD1 Pin List](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Lco1y.jpg)

Comment: Share whole datasheet as well next time.

Answer (score 0):

The stm32 series of microcontrollers do not support EPD displays directly. I think you would need a **EPD controller** in between to make it work.

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I am controlling EPD display on GPIO.. :(

Answer (score 0):

You night be able to generate just the digital inputs, then use an external HV supply from a chip like HV850 and then step it down with inline Zener diodes. I used this approach to make a microflyer based on a piezo speaker!

The HV850 has on/off via digital line and needs +4.2V minimum, max Vout is +/-59V on alternate outputs which is ideal for this purpose.
Simply add a high value resistor on the output side to let it discharge when the panel isn't being driven.
I'd put it in extclk mode and run it at 10Hz to reduce power usage.